# awk count pattern matches and sum the numbers after them

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a file with the following pattern that repeats many times:

```
<Content>Un relax en el ritmo trepidante de New York   showReview(14443615, 'full');
<Date>Mar 22, 2008
<Overall rating>3
<No. Reader>-1
<No. Helpful>-1
<Overall>5
```

So I'm trying to count the number of occurences of `<Overall>` **without counting** `<Overall rating>`. Then I want to sum the numbers that follow after each `<Overall>` tag. This is my code.

```
 awk -F'>' '$1=="<Overall" BEGIN{}
    {
        count++
        sum+=$2
    }
    END{printf "%.2f\n", sum/count}' *filename*
```

Comment: If you remove the BEGIN part, your code seems to work just fine

Comment: Your `BEGIN` is misplaced. It should be `' BEGIN{} $1=="<Overall"{...}`. But since `BEGIN` section is empty, you can just remove it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach

```
$ awk -F'<Overall>' 'NF==2 {sum+=$2; c++} 
                     END   {print (c?sum/c:0)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to sum the values of all lines which contain `<Overall>`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=">";sum=0} $0~/<Overall>/ {sum+=$2} END{print sum}' file
```

An example would be a  file containing the following lines would sum to `175`:

```
...
<Overall>25
<Overall>75
...
<Overall>50
...
<Overall>25
...
```

Comment: IMHO, OP wants to find the average, the sum values with the total pattern count.

Comment: @Inian: Where is there any mention about average? `sum` is not the same thing as `mean`...

Comment: ok agree the mean value see sum/count in OPs attempt. Didn't mean disrespect, thanks!